# How to pre populate collection prototype with existing data from entity in twig?

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, twig

I am new to symfony ,I have received data from entity to my controller and sent it to my twig template now i want to display that data using collection prototype so that i can update that data ,

my js code for creating collection proto

custom.js

```
function addTagForm(collectionHolder, newLinkLi) {

    var prototype = collectionHolder.data('prototype');

    // get the new index
    var index = collectionHolder.data('index');

    // Replace '__name__' in the prototype's HTML to
    // instead be a number based on how many items we have
    var newForm = prototype.replace(/__name__/g, index);

     collectionHolder.data('index', index + 1);
    if(collectionHolder.data('index') <= 6){

         // Display the form in the page in an li, before the "Add a tag" link li
        var newFormLi = $('<li style="width:100%"></li>').append(newForm);

        newLinkLi.before(newFormLi);

        //alert(newFormLi);
    }else{

    $(newLinkLi).remove();

    }

}

});
```

my twig to render it into html

```
 <div class="form-group"> 
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label required" for="product_about_product">Reference List</label><div class="col-sm-10">
   <ul class="c4" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.ReferenceLists.vars.prototype)|e }}">    
                    </ul>
                    </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prototype is used for dynamically creating new form items via javascript. To display existing collection items you need to loop through collection type child forms:

```
<ul>
{% for child in form.ReferenceLists %}
    <li>{{ form_widget(child) }}</li>
{% endfor
</ul>
```